# Change cell color when a different value is encountered

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, colors, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]

Hello there. I Inserted an SQL query in Excel to pick for me data like the above.

Is there a way I can set Excel to automatically Change The Background color each time it encounter a different value.
For example, we have **Kigongo Charles** in Orange, I want that when it meets the next value that is **Not Kigongo Charles**, it changes the Background color to any other color. ie when it reaches **KITAYIMBWA ROBERT**, it changes, then when it reaches **MBULABANTU LAWRENCE**, it changes again to any random color. 
Like that Like that. Am using ***Excel 2016***

Any work around will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in this Macro. I think it does exactly what you want now.

```
Sub ColorIndex()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lColNum As Long
    Dim iColor As Integer
    Dim iDupes As Integer
    Dim bFlag As Boolean

    lRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    lColNum = Selection.Column
    iColor = 2

    For x = 2 To lRows
        bFlag = False
        For y = 2 To x - 1
            If Cells(y, lColNum) = Cells(x, lColNum) Then
                bFlag = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y
        If Not bFlag Then
            iDupes = 0
            For y = x + 1 To lRows
                If Cells(y, lColNum) = Cells(x, lColNum) Then
                    iDupes = iDupes + 1
                End If
            Next y
            If iDupes > 0 Then
                iColor = iColor + 1
                If iColor > 56 Then
                    MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Cells(x, lColNum).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor

                For i = 1 To 5
                    Cells(x, lColNum + i).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
                Next i

                For y = x + 1 To lRows
                    If Cells(y, lColNum) = Cells(x, lColNum) Then
                        Cells(y, lColNum).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
                            For i = 1 To 5
                                Cells(y, lColNum + i).Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
                            Next i
                    End If
                Next y
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

I have edited the code to also make the color changes on the horizontal lines up to 5 cells away from the selected cell. So what you do is select all the names of the database and then run the macro.

Comment: No...

I will be using this template in different databases but the data format is the same. This means that the Data will always be different.

If I have John, Mike and Phillip on one database, 
In other I may have Brian, Ramon, Charlie and Ian. 

I want the change of color to base on the names. (Like in the image, I want the change of color to base on the first column)

Comment: Maybe some one can help me with Macro on this site 
[link](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T012673_Coloring_Identical_Company_Names.html#comment-form-hd)

What I want is something like that but Am failing to customize it.

Comment: @Brian Oh okay I understand it now. very good question I´ll see what I can do since I find this interesting as well.

Comment: @Brian What would you like to have changed in that macro?

Comment: @Brian I have changed the codes to now also color 5 cells to the right of the names.

Comment: I have changed the color range to only pick lighter colors first.
I changed the**iColor = 36**

Thanks a  lot Ramon

Comment: (1) I find the question very unclear. You say your code is doing what the OP wants, but I can't tell what the OP wants, so please tell us what the code does. (2) Specifically, your code appears to use an O(N²) algorithm — i.e., if run on a dataset of 1000 rows, it will execute 1,000,000 loop iterations (because it has loops within loops). This looks like an O(N) problem — `For x = 2 To Rows.Count` / `If CellValue(x) = CellValue(x-1) Then use the same color Else use a different color` / `End If` / `Next x`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What is your code doing that makes it so complicated? … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. Ideally, provide a narrative explanation *and* add comments to the code.